# default методы в интерфейсе

Tags: java

Увидел сегодня код интерфейса, был помечен как `default` и имел тело! Это что такое? Интерфейс же, полностью абстрактный класс.

Comment: Интерфейс это не "полностью абстрактный класс". У класса, даже абстрактного, есть состояние (поля). Интерфейс описывает только поведение (как должны выглядеть методы).

Comment: Вы правы. Шилдт ошибся :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот так. Теперь интерфейсы - это сущности, не имеющие полей. Т.е. можно реализовать методы, которые орудуют константами, другими методами интерфейса или статическими методами других классов